# SpringSecurity replaying a login Grails

Tags: grails, spring-security

In my Grails, I have configured it for Spring Security.  It is best practise to change the value of session tokens after login and logout.  However, I was wondering what should the behaviour be if a login is replayed.

for example, someone logs in, receives a valid session token (HTTP JSession).  They then replay the login, should they get a new token or not?

Comment: How do you replay a login?

Answer (score 1):

I think the section of the documentation regarding [Session Fixation Prevention](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/guide/sessionFixation.html) addresses this potential issue. Unless you have a technical reason for not enabling this feature it's best practice to do so.